# Copy a VkImage after TraceRaysKHR to CPU

Tags: vulkan

Copying a `VkImage` that is being used to render to an offscreen framebuffer gives a black image.

When using a rasterizer the rendered image is non-empty but as soon as I switch to ray tracing the output image is empty:

```cpp
    // Offscreen render pass
    vk::RenderPassBeginInfo offscreenRenderPassBeginInfo;
    // setup framebuffer ..
    if(useRaytracer) {
      helloVk.raytrace(cmdBuf, clearColor);
    } else {
      cmdBuf.beginRenderPass(offscreenRenderPassBeginInfo, vk::SubpassContents::eInline);
      helloVk.rasterize(cmdBuf);
      cmdBuf.endRenderPass();
    }

    // saving to image
    if(write_to_image)
    {
      helloVk.copy_to_image(cmdBuf);
    }
```

Both the ray tracer and rasterizer are using the same resources (e.g. the output image) through shared descriptor sets. I have also a post processing stage where the output is tone mapped & rendered to the swapchain.

I copy the image via a linear image and `vkCmdCopyImage`.

I tried already so much but there are so many question
How can I get the ray traced image? Is it possible to get the output through memory barriers only in a single command buffer as I am using? Should I create an independent command buffer and get the output after a synchronization barrier? Does ray tracing need special `VkPipelineStageFlags`?

Comment: Have you already double-checked if there are any validation errors? If there are none, have you tried using a tool like [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/) or [NVIDIA Nsight Graphics](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics) to see if your image actually contains something? Those tools allow to capture view all the resources that are currently used by your application---including images, and you can take a look if your images actually contain something.

Comment: I'm using the LunarG VulkanSDK and I don't have any validation errors. I'll try NVIDIA Nsight Graphics Tool - that looks promising

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you certain that you have properly set up validation? I think you can force the activation of `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` through the `vkconfig`-tool in your SDK's directory (you find it under `Tools\vkconfig.exe` on Windows) by selecting 1) `"Overridden by the Vulkan Configurator"` and 2) setting `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` to `"Forced On"`. I always enable it in code and install a callback like described e.g. on [vulkan-tutorial.com](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved by now:
When submitting the command buffer to the queue it would require an additional `vkQueueWaitIdle(m_queue)` since ray tracing finishes with a certain latency

Comment: You should *really* not wait on GPU work like this for continued command recording. Use a proper synchronization primitive, i.e. barrier or fence and record subsequent commands in the meantime. Asynchronous work recording and submission is one of the key design features of Vulkan for a reason

Answer (score 2):

You always need to consider synchronization in Vulkan. It is a good idea to learn how this works, because in my opinion this is one of the most important things.

Here one of the blogs:
https://www.khronos.org/blog/understanding-vulkan-synchronization

In summary for lazy people:

- Barriers (Command and Memory), split commands to groups and make sure groups execute in order and not parallel, to synchronize memory access on pipeline stages in one queue.
- Events, similar to Barriers, but uses user-defined "stages", slower than barriers.
- Subpass dependency, synchronizes sub passes.
- Semaphores, synchronize multiple queues, used to synchronize shared data on GPU.
- Fences, same as semaphores, but used to synchronize shared data GPU->CPU.
- Timeline Semaphores (since Vulkan 1.2), synchronize work between CPU and GPU in both directions.
- Queue waiting for idle, same as fences, synchronizes GPU->CPU, but for entire queue not only one particular commit.
- Device waiting for idle, same as queue waiting for idle, synchronizes GPU->CPU, but for all queues.